# Finding string in text file, and then printing several characters beyond that in Python

Tags: python, search, line, substring, nltk

Using Python, I need to search a text file for a string "that/"

I then need get the line number (currently doing so by using enumerate), and print off
"that\" + the remaining text until the next space.

Example text: First/LS thing/NN I/PRP want/VBP to/TO ask/VB is/VBZ if/IN you/PRP remember/VBP any/DT books/NNS that/IN you/PRP read/VBP as/IN a/DT child/NN

Example output: that/IN 14

Here is the code I have right now, which functions correctly, but wherever it should print "that/xx" it prints nothing.

```
with open(filename) as f:
            for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                if 'that/' in line:
                    myString = line
                    mySub = myString[myString.find('that/'):myString.find(' ')]
                    print(mySub, str(num))
                    formattedLines.append(mySub + ' ' + str(num) + '\n')
```

Comment: Which `that` was that again? That `that` with a forward `/` or that `that` with a backslash?

Comment: Is your file formatted with each string in each line?

Comment: your problem is that find(' ') might happen before find('that/'), so try searching for ' ' after searching for 'that/' (just add the indexes returned by find )
also find would return -1 in case it finds nothing and that's gonna be another drawback of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the whitespace can happen before the `that/`. Start your search for the whitespace at the index where `that/` was found:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if 'that/' in line:
            myString = line
            where_is_that = myString.find('that/')
            mySub = myString[where_is_that:myString.find(' ', where_is_that)]
            print(mySub, str(num))
            formattedLines.append(mySub + ' ' + str(num) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly :). Can't believe I didn't think of that! I'm pretty new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think `myString.find(' ')` is the problem. That could find a string before 'that/', so you could trying to get `myString[50:3]`.

Instead, try this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if 'that/' in line:
            start = myString.find('that/')
            offset = myString[start:].find(' ')
            end = start + offset if offset != -1 else len(myString)
            mySub = myString[start:end]
            print(mySub, str(num))
            formattedLines.append(mySub + ' ' + str(num) + '\n')
```

Comment: But, @KyleParker is passing the optional argument to `find`, which indicates from which position the find function must start.

Comment: I don't see an optional argument in the question's code. Could you point it out to me?

Comment: Sorry, @BrendenBrown, I was looking and trying out the code from one of the replies

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your answer, stummjr, the checking for -1 was a useful addition. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take a different approach, and use regex:

```
import re

def analyze(line, word):
    regex = r'\b{0}/[^\W]*'.format(word)
    match = re.search(regex, line)
    return match.group() if match else None

def extract(filename, word):
    output = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        result = analyze(line, word)
        if result:
            output.append(result + ' ' + str(num) + '\n')
    return output
```